# Adding attributes to models only (non DB columns)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to add an attribute `token` to my cart model. Note that I do not want this attribute as a DB column. Please see code below

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  attr_accessor :token

  after_initialize :set_cart_token

  def set_cart_token
    @token = SecureRandom::hex(8)
  end
end
```

When I try to create a Cart `(Cart.create)` and then run `Cart.last.token` I get back nil, how can I read the value of the token I assigned after initializing the Cart object? I do not want `token` to be started in the `carts` table.

Comment: I can not reproduce this scene. BTW, even though you doesn't want store this attribute in table, you should put it in redis or elsewhere whcih can persist it, rather than memory object. When this object is garbage collected, the `token` will change when you load it next time.

Comment: Same code is working for me. Can you please specify the ruby and rails versions?

Comment: You should not get `nil` but you will always get a different value every time you run `Cart.last.token`

Comment: Why don't you want this as a DB column?